# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is the error i'm getting for importing metrics from sklearn package

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Scorpio\Desktop\lab\ml_lab\logistic_reg.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn import metrics
  File "C:\Users\Scorpio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from . import cluster
  File "C:\Users\Scorpio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ._unsupervised import silhouette_samples
  File "C:\Users\Scorpio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\cluster\_unsupervised.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ..pairwise import pairwise_distances_chunked
  File "C:\Users\Scorpio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ._pairwise_distances_reduction import PairwiseDistancesArgKmin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction'
```

I tried

- uninstalling and reinstalling scikit-learn related packages like scipy,numpy...
- also in metrics folder i found the file 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction.cp310-win_amd64 - Copy.pyd' ...is there something wrong cause when i installed sklearn i got the following warning...is this related?

```
DEPRECATION: sklearn is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
```

Comment: How do you import `metrics`?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you _only_ import `metrics`? What's the version of sklearn (maybe you can paste the output of `sklearn.show_versions()`)?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Hi...i actually imported it along with pandas, numpy and other sklearn sub modules...My problem's solved now and i don't know why, I just changed the order i imported the packages...  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier , Import Decision Tree Classifier
from sklearn import metrics,
import pandas as pd  to this order-> pd,tree,model_selection,metrics

Answer (score 0):

I actually dunno the exact reason, but my problem's solved just with updating python(which may probably has nothing to do with this though) and just changing the order in which i imported the modules in the program(i.e., pd,np...then sklearn metrics module)